# P-51 Supercharger Loops

Tags: aviation-history, p-51, supercharger

A WWII pilot once told me that, for fun, they would sometimes take their P-51s up and perform what he called "supercharger loops". They would climb to an altitude below where the supercharger would switch from low to high and then start performing loops. The idea was that they would all adjust their superchargers so that they all switch from low to high and back at the same time. And, eventually, they would be flying synchronized loops.

Has anyone else heard of this?

Is it possible to adjust the changeover speeds from inside the cockpit? Or did that have to be done in the shop?

(There is a supercharger switch in the cockpit, but that merely appears to be a toggle switch that you could use to over-ride the automatic settings.)